# Hacking way to access DOM elements directly in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I'm making in-house app using UIWebView. My app have to introspect HTML DOM and hack something. Is there any way to access internal DOM elements directly? (not through -stringByEvaluating... method)

My app is not for AppStore. So any of hacking/internal/private method access are all welcome :)

Comment: "(not through -stringByEvaluating... method)"  

Sorry, that's the only way. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @fichek Because I have to access all frames in UIWebView regardless of security policy. (i.e. cross-domain frame access)